# Tablerow selection in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablerow

I want to update an image in my window (in javafx) whenever I click on a row of my tableview.
The table is of type `<PopulateTable>`; Here is the code of this class:

```
public class PopulateTable {

    private final SimpleIntegerProperty count;
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;
    private final SimpleStringProperty date;

    public PopulateTable( int count, String name, String date) {
        super();
        this.count = new SimpleIntegerProperty(count);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.date = new SimpleStringProperty(date);
    }
```

The problem is that when I select one line should start a method that requires a file type as a parameter (which I properly stored in an array: 
`final List <file> files = new ArrayList <> ();` ).
I found this tip here on SO but not fuziona me ... where do you think I'm wrong?

Here the method that I found:

```
public void printWaveForm(){ 
    Table1.setRowFactory( tv -> {
        TableRow<PopulateTable> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(event.getClickCount()>=1) {
                    try {
                        plot();
                    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return row;
        });
    }
```

And here, the method that the row of the table should start once selected:

```
public void plot(){
    lineChart.getData().clear();
    xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    yAxis = new NumberAxis();;
    File file = files.get(Table1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    try {
        AudioWaveformCreator.start(file);
        extractedData = Waveform.points();
        XYChart.Series<Number,Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number,Number>();
        for(int i =0; i<extractedData.size(); i++){
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(i,extractedData.get(i)));
        }
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help me.

Comment: Don't use `<>` outside code markup. Stackoverflow treats them as html elements and removes them, unless they are allowed elements, like `<br>`. Use inline code markup (`\`<something>\``), if you want to display something like this.

Comment: thank you and excuse me.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to react to a change of the selected item, you can add a listener to the `selectedIndex` property in the selection model of the `TableView`:

```
Table1.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> plot());
```

instead of using a custom row factory.

Comment: I should put this line instead of  "Table1.setRowFactory( tv -> {" ?

Comment: @ReDePasquale Yes since a click on the row results in a change of the selection (unless the row was already selected; but in that case you do not need to reload the data). Furthermore this will also work, if you modify the selection using the arrow keys. (All assuming the `printWaveForm` method is executed at most one time).

Comment: Still does not work ... maybe because I can not understand what values ​to put instead of (observable, oldValue, newValue). Can you help me, please?

Comment: @ReDePasquale Sorry, just recognized that I somehow forgot the `addListener` part... Edited the answer.

Comment: Works but there's a problem: I need to click on the table at least once before select a row to get the result!

Comment: @ReDePasquale If you want to select plot the currently selected item, you can just call `plot` (with the click approach you would need to do the same, that is if the rows were actually replaced...) Just make sure there actually ***is*** a selected item, i.e. `selectedIndex` >= 0.